# Crop a circle area (ROI) of an image and put it onto a white mask

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to crop a circle area of an image (ROI) and put it onto a white mask with same dimensions and positions.

**Build a white mask:**

```
h, w = img.shape[:2]
mask = np.ones((h,w,3), np.uint8)*255
```

**The circle area (ROI) in the image (--> this is wrong, because it is only a circle and I want an area with all pixels in the circle of this and copy it in the white mask):**

```
roi = cv2.circle(img, (656,517), 505, (0,0,0), -1)
```

How I can copy all the pixels in the circle of the image onto a mask with same dimensions and the same position of the circle?

The image has the dimensions: 1280x1024.

Comment: in c++ there is a mat.copyTo method which accepts masks. provably numpy has something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you just need to use OpenCV's [`bitwise_and`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga60b4d04b251ba5eb1392c34425497e14) method properly, i.e. you need an additional mask for the circular ROI. Also, you need two `bitwise_and` calls, since you want to maintain the white background in the final image.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Original image
image = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png')
cv2.imshow('image', image)

# Circular ROI in original image; must be selected via an additional mask
roi = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], np.uint8)
roi = cv2.circle(roi, (175, 125), 100, 255, cv2.FILLED)
cv2.imshow('roi', roi)

# Target image; white background
mask = np.ones_like(image) * 255
cv2.imshow('mask before operation', mask)

# Copy ROI part from original image to target image
mask = cv2.bitwise_and(mask, image, mask=roi) + cv2.bitwise_and(mask, mask, mask=~roi)
cv2.imshow('mask after operation', mask)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Some input image:

[image: Input]

Generated output:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:  Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:    3.8.1
NumPy:     1.18.1
OpenCV:    4.1.2
----------------------------------------
```